# Regex - "captured group equals" in a condition

Tags: regex, date

I am writing a regex to capture various date formats. To keep it short and flexible, I wanted to pack all the possible combinations of months, days and years into separate groups. Let`s assume I have two dates like this:

01.01. - 31.12.2013

jan - dec 2013

Now, what I want to achieve is to write a regex that would capture both dates like the above ones. that's easy. but I also want to exclude dates like e.g. those:

01.01. - 31 dec 2013

In other words, whenever the months are mixed, I don't want those dates. Also, if the first date doesn't have a day, I don't want that day to be captured in the second one either.

I wanted to build a conditional which captures only the second date's appropriate fields, based on what is found in the first one (so, e.g. if the first date has an alpha month, look only for an alpha month in the second one, ignore numeric). My regex looks like this:

```
(?<firstDay>0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9])[-/\s\.](?<firstMonth>0[1-9]|1[012]|[\p{L}]{3,}|[1-9])\s*[-\s/\.]*\s*(?<secondDay>0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9])[-\s/.]*(?<secondMonth>((?<firstMonth>)(?<=0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9]))(0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])|[\p{L}]{3,})[-\s/\.]*(?<year>(19|20)\d\d|[012][0-9]$)
```

This is all background, but what my question is, **is it possible to check what the captured group is equal to and build a capturing condition based on that?** I found some similar topic on Stack Overflow (can't find it now to referenec, unfortunately), but when I implement it, it stops capturing some proper dates (e.g. 01.01. - 31.12.2013). This is that part:

```
(?<secondMonth>((?<firstMonth>)(?<=0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9]))(0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])|[\p{L}]{3,})
```

Comment: What flavor of regex are you using? What language? For instance, Perl has this nice syntax: `(?(condition)yes-pattern|no-pattern)`

Comment: I do it in C#. The syntax you`re proposing is ok, but how do I write the "condition" part? I only know of the possibility to check if the group is identified or not, but not what value it takes.

Comment: .Net suppors this syntax so it's ok. I didn't fully thought about it as I didn't provide a complete answer, but you could put each alternative in the `firstMonth` capturing group into its own capturing group, this way you can know which alternative matched. `(?<firstMonth>(?<firstMonthNumeric>...)|(?<firstMonthName>...))`

Comment: Second thought: I think you should match everything loosely using regexes, then filter out bad results in code using `match.Groups[...]` to check which group matched. That'll be much easier.

Comment: Nope, with the variety of possible date formats this is very inflexible:) Plus, I have references to the named groups in the C# code.

Comment: Good you have references. What I mean is add more named groups, on top of the existing ones.